# To launch one test from a class with pytest

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, pytest

I have this simple test. I can launch all class but I can't launch one separate test out of this class.

On the screen-shot you see a result of this action. How can I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class TestMouse:
    def setup_method(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("http://schooldata-test.com/")
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_my_first(self):
     self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[4]/div/label").click()
     time.sleep(3)


    def test_new_one(self):
      self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[5]/div/label").click()
      time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: pytest `<your_file>.py::TestMouse::test_my_first`. See relevant docs here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests

Comment: I wanna launch it via Pycharm, when I place my cursor on separate def _test_name in a class and click right button on a mouse, in pop up menu the name of overall test configuration, not of a separate test, after starting, it creating auto configuration in Python folder, and process is ending with: Process finished with exit code 0. My friends don't have similar problem with it and handle their separate tests in class with no trouble...